# How do I access tabbed browsing when using the modern UI Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, tabs, modern-ui

When running Internet Explorer from the the modern UI, I can't find out how to access tabs.  I can create tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, but I'm not sure how to switch between tabs, see what tabs I have open, etc.

How do I navigate between tabs when using the modern UI Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate through tabs in a forward direction or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate in a backwards direction.

There is also a top bar to allow you to add new tabs. You should be able to get the top bar by right clicking over it, or the equivalent touch gestures

Comment: Hover doesn't seem to work, but right click brings up a top bar with thumbnails of all the tabs . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can either right click to bring up the tabs list, or use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the ones you have open.

On touch devices, you should be able to emulate right click with a tap.